# Some Technical Problem with my Blog Post !

Tags: blogs, wordpress

I recently posted a article in my blog site which uses Wordpress for CMS and after posting the article i noticed a set of dots appearing after the post .

I'm not able to remove it .. Can anyone help me ? and explain me what's wrong with it ?!

Comment: Can you give us the URL where you see this? Do you see the dots in the editor too? In the WYSIWYG (Visual) and in the HTML editor?

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the dots in your list of posts?  If yes, you're looking at the list of post excerpts.  Once you click one of the title links, you'll see the post text without trailing dots.

Alternatively you can add [this method](http://www.livexp.net/wordpress/remove-the-suffix-dot-from-the-excerpt.html) to your theme's **functions.php** file to remove the dots for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the whole post or just part of the post? Do you user the  tag in your post? It could be that it is just showing part of the post if you do use the , What theme are you using? It could be the lots of it ...

Looks like we cannot connect the dots :-) yet!

Comment: whoooo ... thanks a lot , i finally found it ! it is due to a plugin called "Sexy bookmark" .. i deactivated and activated it again .Now everything is set :) whenever you upgrade your wordpress version you need to reactivate it again !